# Informe con Itextsharp

Tags: c#, mysql, webforms, itextsharp

Estimados necesito de su ayuda, estoy desarrollando un informe asp.net webform, c#, MySQL e itextsharp y necesito que este informe tenga un formato determinado. La información la recupero a través de la base de datos y la guardo en un `datatable`, hasta hay todo bien, pero lo que necesito es manipular el `datatable` de tal forma, que la información me la pueda sacar por rubros, como en las siguientes imágenes, todo en un mismo archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los campos de la tabla de la base de datos son prácticamente lo mismos que las de las imágenes. Hasta ahora solo puedo sacar la tabla completa que me recupera de la base de datos.

```
private DataTable GetData(MySqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
             ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void ExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strQuery = "sp_exportarPDFInventario";
        string Empresa = ddlEmpresa.SeletedItem.Value;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table width='100%'>");
        sb.Append("<tr><td align='center' style='background-color: #A9F5F2' colspan = '1'><b>R E V A L O R I Z A C I O N E S&nbsp; Y &nbsp;D E P R E C I A C I O N E S</b></td></tr>");
        sb.Append("<hr/>");
        sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");            
        sb.Append("<tr><td><b>EMPRESA: </b>");
        //sb.Append(Empresa);
        sb.Append("</td><td align = 'right'><b>AÑO DE PROCESO: </b>");
        sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
        sb.Append(" </td></tr>");
        sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'><b>CATEGORIA: </b>");
        //sb.Append(Categoria);
        sb.Append("</td></tr>");
        sb.Append("</table>");
        sb.Append("<hr/>");

        sb.Append("<table width='100%' border = '1px'>");
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #CEF6CE'>");
            sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
            sb.Append("</th>");
        }
        sb.Append("</tr>");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(row[column]);
                sb.Append("</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
        }
        var x = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<int>("VALOR COMPRA"))).Sum();
        sb.Append("<tr><td style='background-color: #CEF6CE' align = 'right' colspan = '5'");
        sb.Append(dt.Columns.Count - 1);
        sb.Append("'>TOTAL</td>");
        sb.Append("<td>");
        sb.Append(x);
        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.Append("</tr></table>");

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Muestra el código que has intentado :D

Comment: @fredyfx Actualice la pregunta :D

Comment: ¿Es decir que solo requieres que muestre los totales?

Comment: requiero que me pueda generar una tabla por cada categoria que encuentre, con la información que correponda a esa categoria y los totales de cada una